# Datetime output not outputting as required

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a project currently and the code is playing up. The language I am using is C# and I'm creating a windows form in visual studio 2017. Here is my code and what it outputs. Any ideas on why it's doing this would be much appreciated in order to make my program work properly.

[Here's what the date looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNm1t.png)

[And here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhbNR.png)

Comment: You need to post your code as text, not images, so it can be tested. It's also much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to Date.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy').